# array manipulation question on hackerrank

Tags: c, arrays

My code shows segmentation fault on hackerrank.What will happen if I use long long int?
Here is the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?isFullScreen=true

My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    int queries[m][3];
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][1]);
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][2]);
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][3]);
    }

    int a[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (int j = queries[i][1]; j <= queries[i][2]; j++)
            a[j] = a[j] + queries[i][3];
    }

    int max;
    max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (max < a[i])
            max = a[i];
    }
    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array access is 0-indexed in C, as illustrated by your favourite beginner-level C book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array index out of bounds at .

```
a[j]=a[j]+queries[i][3];
```

because Array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 3 elements) thus 2 is the last index.

and when using the for loops to access the array you might need to start from `0`

### Code

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n,m;
scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
int queries[m][3];
for( int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&queries[i][0]);
    scanf("%d",&queries[i][1]);
    scanf("%d",&queries[i][2]);
}

int a[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    a[i]=0;
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=queries[i][0];j<=queries[i][1];j++)
        a[j]=a[j]+queries[i][2];
}

int max;
max=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(max<a[i])
        max=a[i];
}
printf("%d",max);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: But my array starts from index 1.So how can it be out of bounds?

Comment: although your array starts from index 1 the array ends at the index 2 thus trying to access index 3 would result in error

Comment: You have declared the array as `queries[m][3]` which would create an array of `queries[m][0]` , `queries[m][1] `, `queries[m][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have array index out of bounds error at this line:

```c
a[j] = a[j] + queries[i][3];
```

What value can `i` take?

To avoid similar errors in the future you may want to consider usage of tools for [static code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis). For example, [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) is a free and open source tool that can detect this error:

```
stackoverflow/c-issue.c:23:34: error: Array 'queries[2147483648][3]'  accessed
                               at index queries[*][3], which is out of bounds.
                               [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]                                                                                          
            a[j] = a[j] + queries[i][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

In every loop you are passing boundaries of your array which will cause undefined behavior.

when you declare `int arr [num]` , if you access `arr[x]` while `x=>num` , you are passing boundaries of your array and that will cause undefined behavior , which means you can't predict what will happen.

look

```
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    int queries[m][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][0]);
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][1]);
        scanf("%d", &queries[i][2]);
    }

    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = queries[i][0]; j <= queries[i][1]; j++)
            a[j] = a[j] + queries[i][2];
    }

    int max;
    max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (max < a[i])
            max = a[i];
    }
    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```